# Populate a multidimensional array with values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to populate a multidimensional array with data.
Is there a way to subset the multidimensional array or do I need to run a "foreach" - loop to populate the mentioned array?

Data to be inserted:

```
$dice_hand = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

The multidimensional array skeleton that should receive the above input data:

```
$scorecard = array(
     "player_1" => [
         "scoring" => [
             "rounds" => [
                 "round_1" => [], # Data to be inserted here.
                 "round_2" => [],
                 "round_3" => [],
                 ]
         ]
     ]
);
```

Expected outcome:

```
Array
(
    [player_1] => Array
        (
            [scoring] => Array
                (
                    [rounds] => Array
                        (
                            [round_1] => Array
                                (1,2,3,4,5
                                )

                            [round_2] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [round_3] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Attempt_1: (injecting the array data into the multidimensional array).

```
$scorecard$player_1$scoring$rounds$round_1 = $dice_hand;
```

Comment: Why do you need a foreach? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Does the scheme / structure of the multi-dimension array is known in advance? as what wrong with just `$scorecard["player_1"]["scoring"]["rounds"]["round_1"] = $dice_hand` ?

Comment: You didn't read the manual before posting i see. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case your problem is PHP syntax:

The PHP way of accessing array element is by using `[` and `]` around the key so you need:

```
$scorecard["player_1"]["scoring"]["rounds"]["round_1"] = $dice_hand
```

instead of :

```
$scorecard$player_1$scoring$rounds$round_1 = $dice_hand;
```